# Using the JIRA api

Tags: php, laravel-5, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm just wondering about the structure of Jira. Currently I'm working on an app where users need the ability to login to any Jira they participate.

When I add an application link for the login. Does it only applies for that (cloud) environment?

Is there a way that jira users using the oauth login of atlassian. And that grants the application to see if a user participates in multiple jira products (for instance freelance developers with multiple jira using customers)?

I need a global way to login and let users select the jira platform they want to use. Is this possible? Or do I need to create an application link on every platform?

If someone can give me some information or guide me to some explanations that clears this out would be helpful.

Comment: I don't really understand what is the question. If you make an app that utilizes the JIRA REST API, you must specify the JIRA base URL when you connect. If you connect to multiple JIRA instances, you just have to store multiple URL+user+pass connection strings, and remember which ticket is where.

Comment: You already answered me right now. Thanks